# Selected Options are deleted after renumbering a Dynamic Formset with Select Options using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I have created a dynamic formset for my django project to add and remove forms dynamically. To preserve the value of the fields after renumbering, I am saving the value of the field before renumbering and I am assigning the same value after renumbering the forms. It is working wonderfully in the text inputs but due to my limited experience and knowledge in javascript, I am not able to preserve the value of the selcted options.

Any help and suggestions are highly welcomed.

Thank You.

```
<style type="text/css">
fieldset {
  border: none;
}
</style>

<form id="demo" action="{% url 'my_formset' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}

{{p_form}}

<br>
<hr>

  <!-- Keep Track of the Total Form Here -->
  <input id="total_forms" name="TOTAL_FORM_COUNT" value="0" type="hidden">

  <!-- This is the Form that will be duplicated. We will hide this form. -->
  <fieldset disabled class="empty-form" style="display: none">

    <fieldset class="fieldset" id="fs_0">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="id-f-0-name" name="id-f-0-name" value="">
      <label>Select:</label>
      <select id="id-f-0-item" name="id-f-0-item" placeholder="">
              <option disabled selected value={{None}}> Select Item </option>
              
              <option value='1'>Butter</option>
              <option value='2'>Milk</option>
              <option value='3'>Tofu</option>
              <option value='4'>Soyabeans</option>

            </select>
      <button type="button" id="d-0" class="delete_form" onclick="del_form(this.id);">
        DELETE
      </button>
    </fieldset>
  
  </fieldset>


  <!-- This is where we will insert the form -->
  <fieldset class="forms">

  </fieldset>

  <!-- This is the ADD Button to add New Forms -->
  <fieldset class="controls">
    <button type="button" onclick="addForm();">
      Add new form
    </button>
  </fieldset>

<br>
<br>
<button type="submit">Save</button>

</form>

<br>
<br>


<script type="text/javascript">

var emptyForm = document.querySelector('.empty-form').firstElementChild; // Form to Clone
var formsList = document.querySelector('.forms'); // Div to Add New Form to
var totalForms = document.querySelector("#total_forms"); // To Keep Count of Total Form

var fieldset = document.getElementsByClassName("fieldset"); // To get all individual input form under the formset
var formCount = fieldset.length - 1; // Count for Python starts from 0 and we already have one empty fieldset

var min_form = "{{min_form}}"
 
const del_btnRegex = /d-(\d){1,}/g; 

const formRegex = /f-(\d){1,}-/g; 

function renumber() {

    var fieldsets = document.getElementsByClassName("fieldset");
    for (i = 0; i < fieldsets.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        fieldsets[i].id = `fs_${i}`;

        f = fieldsets[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (c = 0; c < f.length; c++){
          x = f[c];
          const v = x.value;
          x.id = x.id.replace(formRegex, `f-${i}-`);
          x.name = x.name.replace(formRegex, `f-${i}-`);
          x.setAttribute('value',v);
        };
        
        //I am having problems here
        s = fieldsets[i].getElementsByTagName('select');
        for (c = 0; c < s.length; c++){
          x = s[c];
          const vi = x.selectedIndex;
          x.id = x.id.replace(formRegex, `f-${i}-`);
          x.name = x.name.replace(formRegex, `f-${i}-`);
          x.selectedIndex = vi;
        };     

    }
};


function update_del_btn_id() {
    let count = 0;
    for (let f of fieldset) {
        f.innerHTML = f.innerHTML.replace(del_btnRegex, `d-${count++}`)
    }
};


function addForm(){
  //Copy Empty Form
  var newForm = emptyForm.cloneNode(true);
  //Insert the Copied Form
  formsList.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', newForm);

  formCount++; //increases the formCount variable
  //Increase the Total Form Count to loop in python
  totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formCount}`);

  renumber();
  update_del_btn_id();
  show_hide_del_button();
}

function del_form(id){
    //var id = event.srcElement.id.slice(2,);
    var id = id.slice(2,);
    console.log(id);
    document.getElementById(`fs_${id}`).remove();
    formCount--;
    totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formCount}`);
    
    renumber();
    update_del_btn_id();
    show_hide_del_button();
}

function show_hide_del_button() {
    var delBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('delete_form');
    if (delBtn.length-1 <= min_form) {for (var i = delBtn.length-1; i >= 0; i--){delBtn[i].style.display='none'}}
    else{for (var i = delBtn.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {delBtn[i].style.display='inline-block';}};   
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the ID of the Delete button like this to avoid writing to innerHTML. Writing to innerHTML causes forms and select options to reload. Also there is no need to capture the value of the text field or selection option and re-assign the value. It will stay intact.

```
function update_del_btn_id() {
var del_btns = document.getElementsByClassName("delete_form");
    for (i = 0; i < del_btns.length; i++) {
    del_btns[i].id = `d-${i}`;
    }; };


function renumber() {

var fieldsets = document.getElementsByClassName("fieldset");
for (i = 0; i < fieldsets.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    fieldsets[i].id = `fs_${i}`;

    f = fieldsets[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (c = 0; c < f.length; c++){
      x = f[c];
      x.id = x.id.replace(formRegex, `f-${i}-`);
      x.name = x.name.replace(formRegex, `f-${i}-`);
    };
    
    s = fieldsets[i].getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (c = 0; c < s.length; c++){
      x = s[c];
      x.id = x.id.replace(formRegex, `f-${i}-`);
      x.name = x.name.replace(formRegex, `f-${i}-`);
    };     

}};
```